# PHP imagettftext not working with freetype support

Tags: php, gd, imagettftext

My code with function imagettftext doesn't work on linux,however works well on my windows.

```
imagettftext($thumb, 10, 0, 130, 60, $textcolor, "./arial.ttf", "123");
```

I've installed gd lib, freetype,and font

**gd_info() output:**

```
array(12) {
  ["GD Version"]=>
  string(13) "2.0 or higher"
  ["FreeType Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["FreeType Linkage"]=>
  string(13) "with freetype"
  ["T1Lib Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["GIF Read Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["GIF Create Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JPG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PNG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["WBMP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XPM Support"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["XBM Support"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

**Function Result :**

```
array (
  0 => -53534192,
  1 => 32627,
  2 => -53534184,
  3 => 32627,
  4 => -53534176,
  5 => 32627,
  6 => -1169942752,
  7 => 32767,
)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why those figures you get are not correct. It isn't entirely obvious at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

freetype version is not compatible with my Centos version

Comment: Why isn't it compatible? How exactly does that alter the numbers in the output of `imagettftext()`?